# why I'm getting error in npm install -g ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I'm getting error on **`npm install -g ionic`**

also created issue on [**Github**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1887)

**Other information:**

- **Node.js:** i just installed fresh latest version v6.9.4 LTS
- **OS:** Windows 10

Error is:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\aDmIn>npm install -g ionic
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: use uuid module instead
- abbrev@1.0.9 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev
- ansi-regex@2.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex
- ansi-styles@2.2.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-styles
- aproba@1.0.4 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba
- asn1@0.2.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\asn1
- assert-plus@0.2.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\assert-plus
- async@1.5.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\async
- aws-sign2@0.6.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws-sign2
- aws4@1.4.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4
- balanced-match@0.4.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\balanced-match
- buffer-shims@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\buffer-shims
- caseless@0.11.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\caseless
- concat-map@0.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\concat-map
- brace-expansion@1.1.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\brace-expansion
- console-control-strings@1.1.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\console-control-strings
- core-util-is@1.0.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\core-util-is
- dashdash@1.14.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\dashdash
- debug@2.2.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\debug
- delayed-stream@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delayed-stream
- combined-stream@1.0.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\combined-stream
- delegates@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delegates
- escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\escape-string-regexp
- extend@3.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\extend
- extsprintf@1.0.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\extsprintf
- forever-agent@0.6.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\forever-agent
- fs.realpath@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fs.realpath
- generate-function@2.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\generate-function
- generate-object-property@1.2.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\generate-object-property
- assert-plus@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules\assert-plus
- getpass@0.1.6 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass
- graceful-fs@4.1.4 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\graceful-fs
- graceful-readlink@1.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\graceful-readlink
- commander@2.9.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\commander
- has-ansi@2.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-ansi
- has-color@0.1.7 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-color
- has-unicode@2.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-unicode
- hoek@2.16.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\hoek
- boom@2.10.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\boom
- cryptiles@2.0.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\cryptiles
- inherits@2.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inherits
- block-stream@0.0.9 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\block-stream
- ini@1.3.4 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ini
- is-typedarray@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\is-typedarray
- isstream@0.1.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\isstream
- jsbn@0.1.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\jsbn
- ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ecc-jsbn
- jodid25519@1.0.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\jodid25519
- json-schema@0.2.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\json-schema
- json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\json-stringify-safe
- jsonpointer@2.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\jsonpointer
- mime-db@1.23.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\mime-db
- mime-types@2.1.11 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\mime-types
- form-data@1.0.0-rc4 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\form-data
- minimatch@3.0.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimatch
- minimist@0.0.8 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimist
- mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\mkdirp
- nan@2.4.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\nan
- node-uuid@1.4.7 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-uuid
- nopt@3.0.6 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\nopt
- number-is-nan@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\number-is-nan
- code-point-at@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\code-point-at
- is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\is-fullwidth-code-point
- oauth-sign@0.8.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\oauth-sign
- object-assign@4.1.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\object-assign
- path-is-absolute@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\path-is-absolute
- pinkie@2.0.4 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\pinkie
- pinkie-promise@2.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\pinkie-promise
- process-nextick-args@1.0.7 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\process-nextick-args
- qs@6.2.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\qs
- minimist@1.2.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\minimist
- rc@1.1.6 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc
- semver@5.2.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\semver
- set-blocking@2.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\set-blocking
- signal-exit@3.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\signal-exit
- sntp@1.0.9 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sntp
- hawk@3.1.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\hawk
- assert-plus@1.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sshpk\node_modules\assert-plus
- string_decoder@0.10.31 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\string_decoder
- stringstream@0.0.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\stringstream
- strip-ansi@3.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\strip-ansi
- string-width@1.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\string-width
- supports-color@2.0.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\supports-color
- chalk@1.1.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\chalk
- tough-cookie@2.2.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\tough-cookie
- tunnel-agent@0.4.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\tunnel-agent
- tweetnacl@0.13.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\tweetnacl
- sshpk@1.8.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sshpk
- uid-number@0.0.6 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\uid-number
- util-deprecate@1.0.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate
- readable-stream@2.0.6 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\bl\node_modules\readable-stream
- bl@1.1.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\bl
- readable-stream@2.1.4 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\readable-stream
- are-we-there-yet@1.1.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\are-we-there-yet
- verror@1.3.6 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\verror
- jsprim@1.3.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\jsprim
- http-signature@1.1.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\http-signature
- wide-align@1.1.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wide-align
- gauge@2.6.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\gauge
- npmlog@3.1.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\npmlog
- wrappy@1.0.2 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy
- once@1.3.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\once
- inflight@1.0.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inflight
- glob@7.0.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\glob
- rimraf@2.5.3 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rimraf
- fstream@1.0.10 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fstream
- fstream-ignore@1.0.5 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fstream-ignore
- tar@2.2.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\tar
- tar-pack@3.1.4 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\tar-pack
- xtend@4.0.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\xtend
- is-my-json-valid@2.13.1 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\is-my-json-valid
- har-validator@2.0.6 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\har-validator
- request@2.73.0 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\request
- node-pre-gyp@0.6.29 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp
- glob-watcher node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher
- chokidar node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar
- fsevents@1.0.15 node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents
C:\Users\aDmIn\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ionic\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of cross-spawn with cross-spawn@4.0.2
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of mime-types with mime-types@2.0.14
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of request with request@2.51.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.2.0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\aDmIn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-68e1e159
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\aDmIn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-68e1e159' -> 'C:\Users\aDmIn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\aDmIn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-68e1e159' -> 'C:\Users\aDmIn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aDmIn\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

C:\Users\aDmIn>
```

Comment: Clear cache .. `npm cache clean` , then install `ansi` `npm install ansi` then try to install ionic.

Comment: still no luck @atulquest93

Comment: mmm first try to rnu as admin .. other thing ...do you a special not ansi code?

Comment: what do you mean by ansi code?

Comment: **doing these steps worked for me**

 1. uninstall ionic by `npm uninstall -g ionic`

 2. delete `ionic` folder from `C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

 3. install again using `npm install -g ionic --verbose` 


**now i have installed ionic successfully**

    C:\Users\aDmIn>ionic info

    Your system information:

    Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
    Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
    Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
    ios-deploy version: Not installed
    ios-sim version: Not installed
    OS: Windows 10
    Node Version: v6.9.4
    Xcode version: Not installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**doing these steps worked for me**

1. uninstall ionic by `npm uninstall -g ionic`
2. delete `ionic` folder from `C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
3. install again using `npm install -g ionic --verbose`

**now i have installed ionic successfully**

```
C:\Users\aDmIn>ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `npm ls minimatch`, you can see which modules are **depending** on that vulnerable version of `minimatch`. You can then ask the authors of those modules to update their `minimatch` dependency (or better yet you can send a PR for it yourself).

**Just type in "`npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2`" (Without the quotes) for solution MINIMATCH.**

[image]

**If the problem dont solved, try following command:**

```
npm install -g npm
```

The command basically will update your npm and hope it will solve your problem too..

**And for solution `uuid` try:**

```
npm uninstall --save node-uuid
npm install --save uuid
```

The old `node-uuid` module is deprecated and won't be maintained moving forward. The module is still published in NPM for backward compatibility (with the deprecation notice).

If have more erros, please ask to me and I'll try help you.

Comment: **doing these steps worked for me**

 1. uninstall ionic by `npm uninstall -g ionic`

 2. delete `ionic` folder from `C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

 3. install again using `npm install -g ionic --verbose` 


**now i have installed ionic successfully**

    C:\Users\aDmIn>ionic info

    Your system information:

    Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
    Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
    Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
    ios-deploy version: Not installed
    ios-sim version: Not installed
    OS: Windows 10
    Node Version: v6.9.4
    Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: If you solved the problem, post what you do with a answer and mark it.

Comment: Sorry i'm unable to post answer due to some account issue stackoverflow is not allowing me to post answer and saying **We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.**

Comment: but i write it in comment what i exactly done in simple steps

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall ionic by npm uninstall -g ionic
2. delete ionic folder from C:\Users{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
3. install again using npm install -g ionic --verbose